# Which android permission requires access to contacts?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

my app keeps asking for permission to access contacts, but as you can see from picture i don't use READ_CONTACTS. Is there any other permission that also triggers the access to contacts?

[required permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJVpT.png)

Comment: May be you are using google play services which require some permissions related to get accounts, hint : Image is not available. Please for such permissions refer to the android developer website you will find the answer in this link http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET_ACCOUNTS` is part of the same permission group as `READ_CONTACTS`. So, if you are calling `requestPermissions()` for `GET_CONTACTS`, the permission dialog that the user sees will have language focused on contacts.